# How do you trigger a PR build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We use GitHub Enterprise and are migrating our builds from Jenkins to Azure Pipelines. We use GitHub Flow and as a result, we wish to publish artifacts from PR builds. The PR trigger works fine; builds start as soon as a PR is opened or a commit is made to the PR branch. However, there does not appear to be anyway within Azure Pipelines to Queue a PR build manually...

If I queue a build specifying the "merge" branch (i.e. refs/pull/104/merge), the PR merge branch builds, however the environment variables don't appear to have any knowledge that this is a PR build. As a result, some of our conditional tasks that should only execute on PR builds do not get executed.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pull-request-validation

Comment: @Tom Davis Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

After the PR started (and the build started automatically) you can also queue the PR build again manually.

Just go the PR, in the right side you have section "Policies", hover the mouse on the Build policy line, click on the `...` and then click "Queue Build". the build will be triggered with the PR variables.

[image]

[image]